# DateTime parsing is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

While parsing `string` to `DateTime` it throws an exception:

> string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

My code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create(string Sprint_Title, int Length, string Project, string Start_Date)
{
    // Method 1
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    date = DateTime.Parse(Start_Date.Trim().ToString()).Date;  

   //Method 2
    DateTime? date = new DateTime();
    date = DateTime.Parse(Start_Date).Date;
}
```

How can I do this ?

EDIT:

js code is:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });

$("#submit-button").click(function () {
    $("#createForm").dialog("close");

var PL = $("#Project").val();
var SprintTitle = $("#SprintTitle").val();
var Length = $("#Length").val();
var StartDate = $("#StartDate").val();

var json = JSON.stringify({ Sprint_Title: SprintTitle, Length: Length, Project: PL, Start_Date: StartDate });
$.ajax({
    url: "/Sprint/Create",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: json,

    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: input is coming from jquery JSON format

Comment: @Mayank What is the `Start_Date.Trim().ToString()` exactly when you debug your code?

Comment: @Mayank Is `dd-mm-yyyy` your actual data or the format of your data? Clearly, it is not a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParseExact` instead of `Parse` and provide your exact format.

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
string dateString;
DateTime dateValue;

// Parse date with no style flags.
dateString = " 5/01/2009 8:30 AM";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "g", enUS, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);

// Allow a leading space in the date string. 
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "g", enUS, 
                           DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);

// Use custom formats with M and MM.
dateString = "5/01/2009 09:00";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", enUS, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);

// Allow a leading space in the date string. 
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", enUS, 
                        DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);

// Parse a string with time zone information.
dateString = "05/01/2009 01:30:42 PM -05:00"; 
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt zzz", enUS, 
                        DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);

// Allow a leading space in the date string. 
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt zzz", enUS, 
                        DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);

// Parse a string represengting UTC.
dateString = "2008-06-11T16:11:20.0904778Z";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);

// The example displays the following output: 
//    ' 5/01/2009 8:30 AM' is not in an acceptable format. 
//    Converted ' 5/01/2009 8:30 AM' to 5/1/2009 8:30:00 AM (Unspecified). 
//    Converted '5/01/2009 09:00' to 5/1/2009 9:00:00 AM (Unspecified). 
//    '5/01/2009 09:00' is not in an acceptable format. 
//    Converted '05/01/2009 01:30:42 PM -05:00' to 5/1/2009 11:30:42 AM (Local). 
//    Converted '05/01/2009 01:30:42 PM -05:00' to 5/1/2009 6:30:42 PM (Utc). 
//    Converted '2008-06-11T16:11:20.0904778Z' to 6/11/2008 9:11:20 AM (Local). 
//    Converted '2008-06-11T16:11:20.0904778Z' to 6/11/2008 4:11:20 PM (Utc).
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Error says that string input is in wrong format. It is not in `date time` form.

If it is normally in your process, just check input value with `DateTime.TryParse` method.

If it is an unexpected situation, so just check the caller of your method and fix it to send correct datetime value.

Alos I can see that, your method is an `Controller Action` method. So just change parameter types that `string` to `date time`.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a comment, but I don't have enough rep.

run your code and stop the program with a break point so you can read the string Start_Date.

Following example has the string Start_Date = " 19_5_1997 23:59:59:9999".

```
    DateTime FormatDateTime(string Start_Date)
    {
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
        Start_Date = Start_Date.Trim();
        char dateSeperator = '_';
        char timeSeperator = ':';
        char dateTimeSeperator = ' ';
        string temp = "";
        int dateCounter = 0;
        int timeCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Start_Date.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dateSeperator == Start_Date[i])
            {
                if (0 == dateCounter)
                {
                    startDate.AddDays(System.Convert.ToInt32(temp) - startDate.Day);
                }
                else if (1 == dateCounter)
                {
                    startDate.AddMonths(System.Convert.ToInt32(temp) - startDate.Month);
                }
                dateCounter++;
                temp = "";
            }
            else
                if (dateTimeSeperator == Start_Date[i])
                {
                    startDate.AddYears(System.Convert.ToInt32(temp) - startDate.Year);
                    temp = "";
                }
                else
                    if (timeSeperator == Start_Date[i])
                    {
                        if (0 == timeCounter)
                        {
                            startDate.AddHours(System.Convert.ToInt32(temp) - startDate.Hour);
                        }
                        else if (1 == timeCounter)
                        {
                            startDate.AddMinutes(System.Convert.ToInt32(temp) - startDate.Minute);
                        }
                        else if (2 == timeCounter)
                        {
                            startDate.AddSeconds(System.Convert.ToInt32(temp) - startDate.Second);
                        }
                        timeCounter++;
                        temp = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp += Start_Date[i];
                        if (Start_Date.Length == i + 1)
                        {
                            startDate.AddMilliseconds(System.Convert.ToInt32(temp) - startDate.Millisecond);
                        }
                    }
        }
        return startDate;
    }
```

This isn't an efficient way to do this so just check to see if you haven't made a silly mistake anywhere first.